# javascript multiple conditions don't work

Tags: javascript, sorting, drop-down-menu, multiple-conditions

I have a dropdown list ,every option of the list have a year and a month .
I want to sort a select options according to year or month or both that are  .
so I can display options sorted by year or month or year and month together or show everything .
I have the following event :

```
     $('#years,#months').bind('change', function () {
         y = $('#years').val();
         m = $('#months').val();
         $('#files > option').each(function () {
             $(this).show();
         });
         $('#files > option').each(function () {
             string = $(this).text();
              //first situation 
             if (y == 'All' && m == 'All')
                $(this).show();
            // second situation 
             else if ((y == 'All') && string.indexOf(m) == -1) 
                    $(this).hide();
            //third situation 
             else if ( string.indexOf(y) == -1 && m == 'All') 
                  $(this).hide();
             // fourth situation 
             else if (string.indexOf(y) == -1 || string.indexOf(m) == -1) 
               $(this).hide();
         });
     });
```

with html code :

```
<select id='years'>
    <option value='All'>All</option>
    <option value='2013'>2013</option>
    <option value='2012'>2012</option>
</select>
<select id='months'>
    <option value='All'>All</option>
    <option value='Feb'>Feb</option>
    <option value='Jan'>Jan</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
<select id='files' siz='10'>
    <option value='0'>sdgsdfsadfsd1-2013-Feb-1212</option>
    <option value='1'>fsadfadsfadsfadsf2-2012-Feb-123123</option>
    <option value='2'>fsadfadsfadsfadsf3-2012-Jan-123123</option>
    <option value='3'>fsadfadsfadsfadsf4-2013-Jan-123123</option>
    <option value='4'>fsadfadsfadsfadsf5-2012-Feb-123123</option>
    <option value='5'>fsadfadsfadsfadsf6-2013-Feb-123123</option>
    <option value='6'>fsadfadsfadsfadsf7-2013-Feb-123123</option>
    <option value='7'>fsadfadsfadsfadsf8-2013-Jan-123123</option>
    <option value='8'>fsadfadsfadsfadsf9-2012-Jan-123123</option>
    <option value='9'>fsadfadsfadsfadsf10-2013-Feb-123123</option>
    <option value='10'>fsadfadsfadsfadsf11-2012-Feb-123123</option>
</select>
```

second and third situations are not working !! 
it deals with the two conditions (true && false) , (false && true ) as they are same values ! I have no idea why ! 
here's a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qt9DV/)

Comment: Notice that `on` as of jQuery 1.7+ is preferrend to `bind`. Then, explain better what's the matter (and where!). Use `console.log(expression)` or `alert(exp)` to verify condition and debug.

Comment: can't understand your last comment , do you mean it saves its value even I'm assigning it whenever the event is triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is wrong; the last condition is being evaluated when it shouldn't be. (For instance: if `y == 'All'` and also `string.indexOf(m) >= 0`). Try this instead:

```
$('#files > option').each(function () {
    var string = $(this).text();
    var show;
    if (y == 'All') {
        show = m == 'All' || string.indexOf(m) >= 0;
    } else if (m == 'All') {
        show = string.indexOf(y) >= 0;
    } else {
        show = string.indexOf(y) >= 0 && string.indexOf(m) >= 0;
    }
    if (show) $(this).show();
    else $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: thanks for correcting my logic . yours is working :)
is it a scope problem ? can you tell me how can it be fixed ?

Comment: @Sally - It was simply a logic error; nothing to do with scope. With your code, each condition is checked if the previous conditions failed, but you don't want the last of your conditions to be checked if the year or month is `'All'`. (The case where they were both `'All'` was covered by the first condition, but the case where one is `'All'` and the other was valid satisfied the fourth hiding condition because the options did not contain the word `'All'`.)